# Remove parent nodes without childs

Tags: c#, treeview

My procedure works fine with a Do-While but I think it must do a lot of iterations.

Is there a faster way to remove nodes without childs? Remember if you remove a node and it is a single node from its parent node then it must be removed later again.

```
int counter=0;

private void EliminaParentsWithoutChilds()
{
    do
    {
        counter= 0;

        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            RemoveEmptyNodes(node);
        }
    } 
    while (counter > 0);
}

private void RemoveEmptyNodes(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
        {
            RemoveEmptyNodes(childNode);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        node.Remove();
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to flesh out your question a bit. Nodes occur in many contexts. Where are you removing them from. Remember that your reader (unlike you) hasn't been working on your issue for the last hour or three

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that tell you when a node is empty or has only one child in all descendants:

```
private static bool IsUniqueOrEmptyNode(TreeNode node)
{
    return node.Nodes.Count == 0 ||
        (node.Nodes.Count == 1 && IsUniqueOrEmptyNode(node.Nodes[0]));
}
```

Next method remove only the top parent that hasn't childs or that contains only one a single direct child:

```
private static void RemoveEmptyNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (IsUniqueOrEmptyNode(nodes[i]))
        {
            nodes.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        else
        {
            RemoveEmptyNodes(nodes[i].Nodes);
        }
    }
}
```

And a helper method to apply to a `TreeView`:

```
private static void RemoveEmptyNodes(TreeView tree)
{
    RemoveEmptyNodes(tree.Nodes);
}
```